# Li-ion End of life

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries, battery-chemistry

What will be the reason for reduced capacity of Li-ion cell at End of life? What will be the nature of voltage at EOL with respect to BOL? Will it be still reaching something like 3.65 or 3.7?

Comment: Excess heat, CC, CV and UV all contribute to degradation of electrolyte insulation [F] and ESR.[Ohms]  Since there is only 0.7V drop from 3.7 allowed for slow discharge, EOL will be in that range after charging with a short discharge

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert. But I believe the main cause of wear in the cell is degradation of the cathode structure inside the cell.

The voltages stay the same. But the capacity is diminished and ESR is increased. I have cycle tested battery packs and have seen the capacity go down and ESR go up. So this is a direct observation.

Please note that not all lithium ion batteries have a nominal voltage or 3.6 or 3.7. LiFePO4 cells are also considered "lithium ion" cells, but their nominal voltage is 3.2 V.

Comment: Thank you, Did you observe any changes in time taken to reach expected max cell voltage when cycle number increased?

Comment: Definitely. The cell capacity diminished over the course of the test, so the charge time decreased commensurately. We maintained the same CC / CV charge parameters throughtout the test. I don't remember the exact details any more but if we were charging at 1C at the beginning of the test, and that worked out to 3 Amps, then we kept the charge current at 3 Amps throughout the test period. Since the capacity of the cells was going down, by the end of the test, they were charging up faster since we were still charging at 3 Amps.

Comment: I don't remember if I looked at the duration of the CV portion of the charge profile. So I don't know if the CV duration increased or decreased. My expectation is that it would increase as a consequence of increased series resistance. But not enough to compensate for the shorter CC duration.

Comment: _"they were charging up faster since we were still charging at 3 Amps."_ - a lot of that 'reduced capacity' may have been the increased resistance causing the voltage to reach peak value sooner. Charging at a lower current would give higher capacity.

Comment: @BruceAbbott the CC phase was followed by a CV phase which allowed current to taper to some threshold (maybe C/10.... I no longer recall). So the battery should have been receiving a full charge either way. But you could make the same argument regarding discharge. The discharge was to a fixed voltage. So increased ESR may have caused premature termination of discharge due to increased voltage drop. I no longer have the raw data so I can't really check this out. In the end it doesn't matter to me too much whether capacity loss is from increased ESR or actual reduction of C.

Comment: The consumer will just see it as capacity loss either way.

Comment: _"CV phase which allowed current to taper to some threshold (maybe C/10...). So the battery should have been receiving a full charge either way. "_ - no, it wouldn't. C10 would terminate earlier at higher initial current. _"But you could make the same argument regarding discharge"_- yes, but capacity should be measured at very low current. _"The consumer will just see it as capacity loss either way."_ - yes, but they are not seeing the real capacity. For example a cellphone may have greatly reduced talk time (high current) but not less reduced standby time (low current).

Comment: @BruceAbbott this was a rapid discharge application. If anything, we were discharging more slowly than the consumer would be in our test because we had no easy way to dissipate the power. Simply put, the consumer does not care what the C/100 capacity would be because the consumer is discharging at 2 or 3 C. And also the more complex the test is, the greater the chance that you will not do it or it will take so long to set up that the results won't matter any more by the time you get it going.

Comment: @BruceAbbott as a more general comment, when you look at datasheets for lithium ion batteries, they usually have a standard charge and discharge profile, and the cycle life specification is based on this charge and discharge profile or is specified as a note. So when verifying the datasheet cycle life, the way to do it is the way the datasheet says. No effort is made to determine what you are referring to as "the real capacity." Discharge is almost invariable done with a specific current until a specific end of discharge voltage is reached.

Comment: Here's an example battery datasheet [Panasonic CGR18650CG](https://www.master-instruments.com.au/file/59576/1/Panasonic-CGR18650CG.pdf). 'Standard capacity' is defined as 'the average of the capacity (ending voltage of 3 V at 20°C) that is discharged at a standard current (430mA)'. This is 0.2C. As the cell ages its capacity reduces and resistance increases, as you said. At 0.2C the increased resistance won't affect voltage drop much, but at 1C or higher it could significantly reduce the _apparent_ capacity.

Comment: You are definitely right. At the same time, if you look at the cycle life graph in the same datasheet, you will see that it is exactly as I say. The discharge rate used in the graph is 2.15 A and the termination voltage is 3.0 V. That is how they test and report the cycle life. The cells I was testing were high power density cells designed for rapid discharge. But as previously mentioned, we were discharging them slowly anyway. @BruceAbbott

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how the cell changes over time (from the point of view of its user):

Three parameters degrade over time and cycling:

1. The capacity goes down
2. The resistance goes up
3. The self-discharge current goes up

> Will it be still reaching something like 3.65 or 3.7?

The open circuit voltage is affected only slightly (nothing that a general user would notice). However, the voltage sags more under load due to the increased resistance.

---

If you are asking what electrochemical mechanism causes that degradation:

Ideally, when charging and discharging, each lithium ion will pop out of a cavity (not an exact term, but you get the idea) in one electrode  ("deintercalation") at the same time that another lithium ion will pop into a cavity in the other electrode ("intercalation"). In reality, some lithium ions will turn into lithium metal and block some of those cavities, rendering them unavailable to store charge. That reduces the cell capacity. As more and more lithium metal forms, it creates a path for current to flow directly between the electrodes, which increases the self-discharge current.